# Why isn't my responsive website acting responsive on the iphone?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, responsive-design

I have a responsive webpage that changes as the screen resolution changes, but for some reason, it loads the non-responsive version whenever I load the page on my iPhone:

http://rayku.com/register

The home page is fully responsive on the iPhone (http://rayku.com/home), but I'm not sure why the registration page isn't. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an iPhone, so I can't test this, but it looks like you're missing a meta tag from your `<head>` tag.  Try adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `viewport` `meta` tag (which is correctly present on the home page).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```